# How to make axios get request dynamically in react.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am trying to make an axios get request in react.
Where the url will be dynamic.
The react code is:

```
class Players extends React.Component {
  state = {
    players: [],
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const res = await axios.get(
        "https://nba-players.herokuapp.com/players-stats/Aaron" {*I want to make this name dynamic and grab this name from a form */}
      );
      this.setState({ players: res.data });
    };
    fetchData();
  }
  render() {
    return <div>{this.state.players.team_name}</div>;
  }
}
```

The html form is:

```
<form id="form">
  <label for="name">Type name</label>
  <input id="name" type="text" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

When the user types the name in the input and clicks on submit in this `form`, 
then,It will be redirected to the react app and the axios get request will be `https://nba-players.herokuapp.com/players-stats/` + `The name user typed in that form` 
so that, I can get data in my react app accordingly to the name that the user typed in the `form`.

Here is my approach:

React code:

```
class Players extends React.Component {
  state = {
    players: [],
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const res = await axios.get("https://nba-players.herokuapp.com/players-stats/" + window.location.href.split('/')[4]);
      this.setState({ players: res.data });
    };
    fetchData();
  }
  render() {
    return <div>{this.state.players.team_name}</div>;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<form id="form">
  <label for="name">Type name</label>
  <input id="name" type="text" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

JQuery:

```
$("#form").on("submit", function () {
        $(this).attr(
          "action",
          "http://localhost:3000/" + $("input").val() //react project on port 3000
        );
      });
```

Is there are any better way to do it?

Comment: Where is this `form`? Is it not in the JSX?

Comment: Try making a `fetchData` takes an arbitrary part of the URL (the player's name) as an argument. The name can be captured from a form value and stored in the state. `<input onChange={(event) => this.setState({ playerName: event.target.value })}`

Comment: If the HTML form is not part of the React app, then when you redirect you can append the player's name as a query parameter in the React app's URL like `http://localhost:3000/players/?name=kevin%20durant`. React can grab that `name` parameter from the URL.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
Should I grab ```name``` parameter from React app's URL by spliting ```window.location.href``` or is there any better way to do it? I don't know . Cause, I am new in web development.

Comment: are you using react router? They got prop functions that you could use: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params

Comment: Nope, I am new in react and don't know about react router. But I will try this.
Thank you very much for your advice...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very common use case. You want to have a state that is connected to an input field of an form. You want the state to represent the latest change of the input field and onSubmit of the form you want to take that state and use it, e.g. to catch something from a REST API.

Have a look at the official documentation of React: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

It's a step to step tutorial on how to connect input to state.

Let me write down the most important parts:

Every input field that you describe in your render return jsx has an `onChange` callback function that you can use.

`<input onChange={myCallbackFunction} />`

This callback function will be called every time the value of the input field changes.

```
const myCallbackFunction = (event) => {
   // standard web api change event
   const newValue = event.target.value;
   // update state based on input field changes
   this.setState({ playerName: newValue });
}
```

Now you got your state updated based on the input field.

The last step is to also create a onSubmit callback function which triggers the axios call.

`<form onSubmit={mySubmitFunction}>`

```
const mySubmitFunction = (event) => {
   // standard web api submit event
   event.preventDefault();
   // use state
   const url = `https://nba-players.herokuapp.com/players-stats/${this.state.playerName}`
  // TODO call axios with dynamic url
}
```

Comment: Be aware that there are function and class components in React. You described a class component, so make sure that you translate any solution to class component syntax :)